# Getting Error with React: Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Function DocumentReference.set() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value:

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

**Payment.js**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { CardElement, useElements, useStripe } from '@stripe/react-stripe-js';
import { Link, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import BookingProduct from '../bookingproduct/BookingProduct';
import './Payment.css';
import { useStateValue } from '../../StateProvider';
import { getBasketTotal } from '../../reducer';
import CurrencyFormat from 'react-currency-format';
import axios from '../../axios';
import { db } from '../../firebase';


const Payment = () => {

    const [{ basket, user }, dispatch] = useStateValue();

    const navigate = useNavigate();

    // const stripe = loadStripe('secret_key');
    const stripe = useStripe();
    const elements = useElements();

    const [succeeded, setSucceeded] = useState(false);
    const [processing, setProcessing] = useState("");
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);
    const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(true);
    const [clientSecret, setClientSecret] = useState(true);

    useEffect(() => {
        
        // generate the special stripe secret which allows us to charge a customer
        const getClientSecret = async () => {
            const response = await axios({
                method: 'post',
                // Stripe expects the total in a currencies subunits => Rupees to Paisa
                url: `/payments/create?total=${getBasketTotal(basket) * 100}`
            });
            setClientSecret(response.data.clientSecret)
        }

        getClientSecret();
    }, [basket])

    console.log('THE SECRET IS >>>', clientSecret)
    console.log('', user)

    const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
        // Do all stripe stuff...
        event.preventDefault();
        setProcessing(true);

        const payload = await stripe.confirmCardPayment(clientSecret, {
            payment_method: {
                card: elements.getElement(CardElement)
            }
        }).then(({ paymentIntent }) => {
            // paymentIntent = payment confirmation
            
            console.log({ user, basket, paymentIntent })
```

**Console Output :**
[Console Output : Error Found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHL80.jpg)

```
            // adding orders on order page with user details
            db
                .collection('users')
                .doc(user?.uid)
                .collection('orders')
                .doc(paymentIntent.id)
```

**//Error - 1 :** I think I'm getting first error in this place while I want to create a collection on firebase.

[firebase error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/orjkP.png)

```
                .set({
                    basket: basket,
                    amount: paymentIntent.amount,
                    created: paymentIntent.created
                })

            setSucceeded(true);
            setError(null);
            setProcessing(false);

            dispatch({
                type: 'EMPTY_BASKET'
            })

            // redirect the page and never back to payment page again since the payment is done
```

// and here the payment page is successfully replaced by the order page after successful order... and all order details will be visible on order page [order page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwwuQ.png)

```
            navigate('/order', { replace: true })
        })
    }

    const handleChange = event => {
        // card element work
        // listen for changes in the CardElement
        // and display any errors as the customer types their card details
        setDisabled(event.empty);
        setError(event.error ? event.error.message : "");
    }
```

I think I've elaborated everything according to my error.... also added error screenshots.

Comment: What debugging have you done? Even logging out all the variable values would be a start, eg `console.log({ user, basket, paymentIntent })`

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [**minimal**, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (with extra focus on the _minimal_). Work through one problem at a time. And FYI, you have forgotten to wait for the Firebase document to be written before continuing

Comment: @Phil there does not print anything in console for console.log({ user, basket, paymentIntent })

Comment: @Phil ok i added it below .set({}) ... and now according to you I got console output...

Comment: Ah, you have a `nostock: undefined` value in `basket`. You'll need to fix that

Comment: Should probably ask a new question. I'd also highly recommend you keep it as minimal as possible and do a heap of debugging before asking